# vue-fullcalendar - css class and new line break not working

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar, vuejs2, vue-component

does anyone here uses the *vue-fullcalendar* component that was made by Wanderxx?

I'm having a problem on two things:

(1) css class not applied **[SOLVED]**

I populated each eventData object with this computed function:

```js
  eventsArr: function(){
        let newArr = [];
        let arrEvents = this.transactions;
        for (let x in arrEvents){
          let eventData = new Object();
          if(arrEvents[x].Status == "Reserved"){
            let title = arrEvents[x].Product_name + " \n " + arrEvents[x].userData.Account_name;
            eventData.title = title;
            eventData.start = arrEvents[x].dateValid;
            eventData.end = arrEvents[x].dateValid;
            eventData.cssClass = 'RTW';
            newArr.push(eventData);
          }
          else if(arrEvents[x].Status == "Accepted"){
            let title = arrEvents[x].Product_Type + " \n " + arrEvents[x].userData.Account_name;
            eventData.title = title;
            eventData.start = arrEvents[x].dateFinish;
            eventData.end = arrEvents[x].datefinish;
            eventData.cssClass = 'mto';
            newArr.push(eventData);
          }
        }
        return newArr;
    }
```

as you can see in the prop `cssClass` is the class `mto` which is declared in the css section like this:

```css
.mto{
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

the event should appear in a white font and an orange background. But it was not applied and the style remains the same as default (same case with the `RTW` cssClass). when I inspect the page the `mto` class is present in the tag so I don't know where did I go wrong.

(2) **new line break not working**

one of the prop is `title` and before storing it, I made a variable first and store it like this:

```js
let title = arrEvents[x].Product_Type + " \n " + arrEvents[x].userData.Account_name;
eventData.title = title;
```

My goal was to display the title as a two-liner. But it doesn't work and it still looke like this:

[image]

I don't want it to look like that and I want the full name to be displayed. How do I make it a two-liner?

Comment: The first error is pretty straight forward. You need to define `eventData` as `let eventData = {}` first before you can fill/add properties to it

Comment: @samayo I already did `let eventData = new Object();`

Comment: I don't see it in your code

Comment: @samayo sorry. I updated it.

Comment: Well now the error has changed. Check it also i'm not sure if this is correct `for (let x in arrEvents){}`

Comment: @samayo I'm pretty sure that _for/in_ loop is correct.

Comment: Can you console.log something inside the forloop within the two conditional blocks

Comment: @samayo I put a button that console.log() the whole content the of the returned array of the computed function. is that okay for you?

Comment: For the CSS, have you looked through the styles being applied to the `.mto` element? Maybe it's being applied but isn't specific enough and is getting overridden.

Comment: @NathanHeffley I can't say it is overridden because it's not in the styles. but the class was definitely included in the tag. I don't understand why is it like that.

Comment: I mean open up your inspector tools and search through the code for that custom `.mto` class you made. If you've done that and can't find the class, you probably have a problem with your build tools, or you aren't including your custom CSS.

Comment: @NathanHeffley that's what I did. hmmm...

Comment: @NathanHeffley I did a test. in my style section I changed it from `<style scoped>` to `<style>` and the mto class appeared in the console (and it's being overridden). I'm guessing that since I registered the calendar component locally, the mto class doesn't affect it since it's only scoped to that specific parent component.

Comment: @NathanHeffley I solved the css problem using `!important` so thank you for leading me to that

Answer (score 0):

I can't make the demo for the module work, but on the css the event element has set the property `text-oveflow` to `ellipsis`:

```
.full-calendar-body .dates .dates-events .events-week .events-day .event-box .event-item {
  ...
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

You are going to have to overwrite it.
Also, if you want to make the text to flow on two (or more) lines, you are going to overwrite the white-space property too.